# Отправка сообщений без перезагрузки страницы.

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте. Дело в том, что у меня не получается реализовать отправку сообщений без перезагрузки страницы. Ну как, почти получилось. использовал `jQuery.ajax()`. Вот код.

```
$(function(){
    $('#postform').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/board.php',
            data: $('#postform').serialize(),
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(msg){
                $(".postmessage").append(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Все вроде бы хорошо, но после того, как я нажимаю кнопку "Отправить", ничего не происходит секунды 2, потом появляется мое отправленное сообщение, а с ним и вся страница с темой и сообщениями повторяющаяся раз 10. Перезагружаю страницу и все становится нормально. Что не так?
До этого там не было

```
  success: function(msg){
    $(".postmessage").append(msg);
  }
```

Но сообщения не подгружались.

Comment: async: true

Comment: а что у вас возвращает сервер ?

Comment: @GenchiK, поставил, теперь страница перезагружается
@Alexandr Vasilenko, я не знаю.

Answer (score 2):

1. При отправке ajax нужно добавить какой нибудь loading, чтобы не происходило непонятной тишины на 2 секунды.
2. Серевр должен возвращать только тот html, который нужно вставить в .postmessage, а не всю страницу.
3. Лучше убрать строчку  async: false, потому как при синхронном запросе происходит(должно происходить) подвисание браузера, лучше использовать асинхронные запросы, по умолчанию в jQuery асинхронный запрос.

Материал для изучения:

http://jquery-docs.ru/ajax/jquery-ajax/

http://habrahabr.ru/post/42426/

Дополнение:
Вот код в самом низу board.php, тут идет вызов функции, которая делает редирект на свеженаписанный тред или пост.

```
if( $_POST['redirecttothread'] == 1 || $_POST['em'] == 'return' || $_POST['em'] == 'noko') {
    if ($thread_replyto == "0") {
        do_redirect(KU_BOARDSPATH . '/' . $board_class->board['name'] . '/res/' . $post_id . '.html', true, $imagefile_name);
    } else {
        do_redirect(KU_BOARDSPATH . '/' . $board_class->board['name'] . '/res/' . $thread_replyto . '.html', true, $imagefile_name);
    }
} else {
    do_redirect(KU_BOARDSPATH . '/' . $board_class->board['name'] . '/', true, $imagefile_name);
}
```

Если же мы добавим какой нибудь параметр в POST запросе, например ajax=true и в php будем проверять. Далее если это ajax, то возвращаем текст в html или json.

JSON хорош тем, что вместо обычного текста можно обмениваться именно данными с сервера

```
{
    "post" : "Свеженагаженный пост",
    "time" : "12345646511",
    "user" : "Анонимус",
    "error" : false
}

/// К примеру если юзер забанен, то

{
    "error" : "Вы забанены!"
}
/// далее можно вывести alert(msg.error)
```

Далее в браузере если нужно обрабатываем и выводим. HTML хорош тем, что не нужно заморачиваться просто вставили и все $(".postmessage").append(msg);

На счет php, тут уж нужно поизучать движок, возможно лучше велосипеды не в этом файле прикручивать, это дело не 5ти минут, за просто так никто не сделает. Удачи в создании имборджа!

Comment: >Серевр должен возвращать только тот html, который нужно вставить в .postmessage, а не всю страницу. 

Кусаба так не умеет, она отдаст всю страницу.

Comment: Хм... Можно подумать какие нибудь костыли, но это все уже не то. Приедется коварять код php, якак понимаю это движок имборджев kusaba. На него уже 31 августа 2007  разработчик положил большой МПХ, там таки  морально все устарело неверное.

Comment: Ага, она самая. Ну скажите хоть в каком направлении копать.
Ну, Аноны на сайте создателя выкладывают какие-то стабильные версии. Ковыряют их.

Comment: дай линк на движок

Comment: этот с плюшами всякими, в нем я и пытаюсь добиться отмены перезагрузки - http://rghost.ru/43340147
это какая-то стабильная версия - http://kusabax.cultnet.net/svn/dl.php?path=%2Fstable%2F&rev=0&isdir=1
тут все остальное - http://kusabax.cultnet.net/

Comment: Ответ выше.

Comment: Хммм, спасибо конечно большое за потраченное время, но я так и не понял что мне делать.

Comment: Может мне проще вам заплатить будет?

Comment: Это здесь if( $_POST['redirecttothread'] == 1 нужно вписать ajax=true? Вместо redirecttothread?

Comment: Нет, порсто нужно немного почитать о php, поэксперементировать. 
Для начала почитать основы языка, операторы if/else, методы $_POST/$_GET
Потом уже как эти вещи станут понятны, то уже можно что то пробовать.

Answer (score 0):

Для отмены перезагрузки страницы добавьте в конце обработчика сабмита return false;
потому как e.preventDefault(); мне лично помогал мало

```
$(function(){
    $('#postform').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({ ... });
        **return false;**
    });
});
```

Comment: Использую вот этот скрипт:
$(function(){
$('#postform').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
url: 'http://trollchan.0zed.com/<?php echo "?thread=" .$thread['id']; ?>',
data: $('#postform').serialize(),
async: false,
type: 'POST',
dataType: "html",
success : function(data){
$(".thread").html(data);
return false;
}
});
});
});
Добавил то, что вы говорили, все вроде бы нормально, но после отправки и подгрузки сообщения дублируется футер и хэдер.У меня там все отдельно, хедер, форма, тела, футер. Подключается все это через include, может в этом дело?
Еще подключил query-1.4.2.min.js

Comment: > Еще подключил query-1.4.2.min.js
как я понял jQuery уже был подключен. Вы просто заменили библиотеку или подключили еще одну? Если еще одну - отключайте, иначе задолбаетесь баги ловить;)

> после отправки и подгрузки сообщения дублируется футер и хэдер
Это уже сервер отдает, используйте вначале проверку что-то типа

if( isset($_POST) && isset(переменные в $_POST)){
 //здесь выводим ответ для ajax
 echo $ajaxResponse;
 // останавливаем скрипт
 die();
}
// дальше идет вывод страницы, если нет $_POST - обычный вывод
Удачи)